# Unable to install Shopify Custom App in live store

Tags: shopify

I am creating a custom app for my Shopify store.
After creating merchant url I am unable to install it in my live store.The button is disabled

[image]

No Error messages is being shown as well, Am I missing something here ?

Comment: It was an issue from the Shopify side which got resolved later.

Comment: @Nithin_phill did you get any solution?

Comment: This seems to be an intermittent issue. I face this issues sometimes and sometimes not but don't know what changes